# django signals to user browser

Tags: python, django

ok, look, there are many users in db. and there are many magazines in db. user can subscribe to one or many magazines.

I want to do something like:

if there is some new entry in a magazine that the user has subscribed to, then user should get instant notification.

I have never done anything in signaling business in django. I am thinking about using `post_save()` of magazine model and send signal to.. (my question begins from here) what? and how can I show in users browser that notification?

any help is appreciated

Comment: Look into this service http://pusher.com/ - or roll your own with websockets.

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial. The user is generally bound to the request/response cycles of HTTP. There are some concepts that can do that. https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio might be a good start to develop a pushing service.

Answer (score 1):

Signals are internal to Django.  What you want is async communication, like [django-websockets-redis](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis).  Django however is notoriously bad at doing async.  I use a separate [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) server where I need it and bridge it by exposing internal interfaces for dataflow between the instances.